# Animation to show ImageView from left to right

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Animate ImageView width without scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860780/animate-imageview-width-without-scaling)

What I'm trying to do is to create an animation where an ImageView is shown starting from the left to the right (clipping animation?). The image should not be scaled.

I tried changing the scaleType and then applying a ScaleAnimation directly to that ImageView:

Layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/graphImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/stroom_grafiek"
    />
```

Java:

```
scale = new ScaleAnimation((float)0,
        (float)1, (float)1, (float)1,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)1);
scale.setDuration(1000);

graphImage.startAnimation(scale);
```

I also tried to put the ImageView inside a RelativeLayout, and then apply the animation to the RelativeLayout:

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/graphImageInnerWrap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/graphImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/stroom_grafiek"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
scale = new ScaleAnimation((float)0,
        (float)1, (float)1, (float)1,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)1);
scale.setDuration(1000);

graphImageInnerWrap.startAnimation(scale);
```

In both cases the ImageView is still being scaled.
I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried using TranslateAnimation for the same effect?

Comment: You mean the image view translate from left to right? Don't want to scle it?

Comment: If you just want the image to move from left to right you could use TranslateAnimation. You don't need to scale it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava Yeah, see the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860780/animate-imageview-width-without-scaling

Answer (score 9):

Try translate animation as

```
Animation animation1=new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
animation1.setDuration(5000);
imageview.startAnimation(animation1);
```

and you can set your coordinates in `TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY)` as I have done in above code

Comment: I don't want to move the image from left to right. The position of the image is fixed. Think of it as an piece of paper which it slowly pulled of an image to the right so the image slowly appears starting from the left.

Comment: thanks for the tip.. is it possible to set the image at the final position after the animation. Because in my case the image moves back to old position after animation is over.

Comment: @Thilek this can be done by a little trick... u will have to use that particular image in two places.. first place is where your animation starts and second where it ends....initially make that second image visibility GONE and when the animation completes make it visible and at the same time make first image visibility GONE... hope this helps

Comment: @maninder singh This is helpful to me. but My image view again resets to the original position where I have placed the image view in my relative layout. how to stop the image on the where animation ends

Comment: @manindersingh: When image is moved then blank space is visible how can we control that ?