# Animate ImageView width without scaling

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to animate an ImageView so it's slowly shown from left to right. 
When [I asked this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012284/animation-to-show-imageview-from-left-to-right) I was having trouble to explain what I wanted, so this time I created the desired effect using HTML / JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/E2uDE/

What would be the best way to get this effect in Android?

I tried changing the scaleType and then applying a ScaleAnimation directly to that ImageView:

**Layout:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/graphImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/stroom_grafiek"
    />
```

**Java:**

```
scale = new ScaleAnimation((float)0,
        (float)1, (float)1, (float)1,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)1);
scale.setDuration(1000);

graphImage.startAnimation(scale);
```

But this stil scales the image.

I also tried wrapping the ImageView in a FrameLayout, hoping I could just animate the FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clipChildren="true"">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left|clip_horizontal" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This will still try to scale my ImageView to fit inside the FrameLayout.

Comment: maybe using Android Animations will help you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to do this - one way is to simply change the clip on the canvas (i.e. the area where the view is allowed to draw) of the `ImageView` drawing your image. Slowly increasing the right-hand edge of the draw bounds will result in same effect as in your example link.

I have written some [example code](https://github.com/antonyt/CoveredImageView) which illustrates this technique. If you download/build/run the project, clicking on the image will run the reveal animation.

Have a look at the `onDraw` method of the [CoveredImageView](https://github.com/antonyt/CoveredImageView/blob/master/src/com/antonyt/coveredimageview/CoveredImageView.java) class, which has the following basic structure:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    canvas.getClipBounds(mRect);
    mRect.right = ...;
    canvas.clipRect(mRect);
    ...
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    ...
    invalidate();
}
```

The clip is adjusted and then invalidate() is called, causing onDraw() to be called again.

I have also written some code to interpolate the right clip value from the elapsed time, which does not depend on any particular version of Android. However, as a note, from Android 3.0 there is a new animation framework and a [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) class which could help perform such tasks.

Comment: @antonyt The Github link you have given me does not have gen folder as well have it supports which version it does not clarify that How  can i use the project to see the animations , According to me Gen Folder is generated automaticallly but it is not doing so

Comment: I arbitrarily chose API level 7 (v2.1) as the minimum, but it can probably go lower - this is specified in the manifest. The project is compiled with API 17 (4.2), however. Gen is automatically created when you compile - maybe you have having problems building the project - have a look at the 'Problems' window in Eclipse for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could overlap your imageview with another one, for example one with a plain white drawable. Then you can animate the overlapping imageview without worrying about scale until it has a width of 0 and remove it. For that to work you have to place your imageView in a RelativeLayout ofc.