# Smooth Translation of a View across Fragments in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I have to do simple translation , i have to move image from left (Activity & Fragment 1 are on screen)
Now as I am scrolling the Page(Fragment) the Fragment 1 is going toward left , Fragment 2 is coming from right and the Image should also translate from left to right

**activity_intro.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"

tools:context="com.example.rahulkumarlohra.retrofitsample.Retro.Activity.IntroActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@mipmap/plus_icon_blue_xxhdpi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="143dp" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@mipmap/plus_icon_blue_xxhdpi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_marginTop="81dp" />
```

The above code is activity_intro.xml

I have a imageView outside ViewPager , i want to translate this imageView across fragments in ViewPager.Right now I am able to do translation of this imageView using `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` but the translation isn't smooth

Below is the code for `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            Log.d(TAG,"position:"+position);
            Log.d(TAG,"positionOffset:"+positionOffset);
            Log.d(TAG,"positionOffsetPixels:"+positionOffsetPixels);

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

            float movement = (Float.parseFloat(df.format(positionOffset)));

            int rlWidth = relativeLayout.getWidth();
            IntroActivity.c = movement;

            imageView1.animate().translationX(positionOffsetPixels).start();
            if(movement!=IntroActivity.c)
            {

                if(movement>IntroActivity.c)
                {
                    if(movement-IntroActivity.c>0.03)
                    {

                        imageView1.animate().translationX(rlWidth*movement).withLayer().start();
                        IntroActivity.c = movement;

                    }
                }else {

                    if(IntroActivity.c-movement>0.03)
                    {

                        imageView1.animate().translationX(rlWidth*movement).withLayer().start();
                        IntroActivity.c = movement;

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onPage Selected position:"+position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Animation to show ImageView from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012284/animation-to-show-imageview-from-left-to-right)

OR

Use style for the image

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"/> 

 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="600"/>
```